# using hash to determine whether 2 dataframes are identical (PART 01)

Tags: r, hash

I have created a dataset using [WHO ATC/DDD Index](http://www.whocc.no/atc_ddd_index/) a few months before and I want to make sure if the database online remains unchanged today, so I downloaded it again and try to use the `digest` package in R to do the comparison.

The two dataset (in txt format) can be downloaded [here](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/Uule8TIa7/Us8x2qKVzUPQ). (I am aware that you may think the files are unsafe and may have virus, but I don't know how to generate a dummy dataset to replicate the issue I have now, so I upload the dataset finally)

And I have written a little script as below:

```
library(digest)

ddd.old <- read.table("ddd.table.old.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ddd.new <- read.table("ddd.table.new.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


ddd.old[,"ddd"] <- as.character(ddd.old[,"ddd"])
ddd.new[,"ddd"] <- as.character(ddd.new[,"ddd"])

ddd.old <- data.frame(ddd.old, hash = apply(ddd.old, 1, digest),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ddd.new <- data.frame(ddd.new, hash = apply(ddd.new, 1, digest),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

ddd.old <- ddd.old[order(ddd.old[,"hash"]),]
ddd.new <- ddd.new[order(ddd.new[,"hash"]),]
```

And something really interesting happens when I do the checking:

```
> table(ddd.old[,"hash"]%in%ddd.new[,"hash"]) #line01

TRUE 
 506 
> table(ddd.new[,"hash"]%in%ddd.old[,"hash"]) #line02

TRUE 
 506 
> digest(ddd.old[,"hash"])==digest(ddd.new[,"hash"]) #line03
[1] TRUE
> digest(ddd.old)==digest(ddd.new) #line04
[1] FALSE
```

- `line01` and `line02` shows that every rows in `ddd.old` can be found in `ddd.new`, and vice versa.
- `line03` shows that the `hash` column for both dataframe are the same
- `line04` shows that the two dataframe are different

What happen? Both dataframe with the identical rows (from `line01` and `line02`), same order (from `line03`), but are different? (from `line04`)

Or do I have any misunderstanding about `digest`? Thanks.

Comment: You could use `all.equal(ddd.old, ddd.new)` to check differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read in data as before.

```
ddd.old <- read.table("ddd.table.old.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ddd.new <- read.table("ddd.table.new.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ddd.old[,"ddd"] <- as.character(ddd.old[,"ddd"])
ddd.new[,"ddd"] <- as.character(ddd.new[,"ddd"])
```

Like Marek said, start by checking for differences with `all.equal`.

```
all.equal(ddd.old, ddd.new)
[1] "Component 6: 4 string mismatches" 
[2] "Component 8: 24 string mismatches"
```

So we just need to look at columns 6 and 8.

```
different.old <- ddd.old[, c(6, 8)]   
different.new <- ddd.new[, c(6, 8)]
```

Hash these columns.

```
hash.old <- apply(different.old, 1, digest)
hash.new <- apply(different.new, 1, digest)
```

And find the rows where they don't match.

```
different_rows <- which(hash.old != hash.new)  #which is optional
```

Finally, combine the datasets.

```
cbind(different.old[different_rows, ], different.new[different_rows, ])
```